# Active Sources Extraction

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, eeg, neuroimaging, meg

I am using the LORETA-KEY software for source localization, which gives as an output the current density of each voxel.

No voxel has zero current density, so which method should be used to decide the active sources?

Is the Region Of Interest (ROI) appropiate?

Comment: It's a good question but most likely you should not be throwing out any sources.